# WPF ListView Key Search Issue

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I am using MVVM to show a list data in ListView. The ListView is very simple as follow:

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Width="100" Content="First Name" />
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Width="100" Content="Last Name" />
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>
```

I bind a list of customer objects into ListView and the issue comes when I highlight a item in the ListView and start typing `T`. The ListView will highlight the next item each time you type a `T` character.

By spending some time to find out the issue, I track down it is because that my customer object has namespace `TestMVVMProject` so I think the `ToString()` function for customer object is always return `TestMVVMProject.Customer`

Can anyone give me some idea how to stop this behaviour?

Comment: If your hunch is right, setting `DisplayMemberPath` on the `ListView` to say `LastName` will work "properly". However, are you looking for a solution that uses the first column?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the solution using first column. What I try to do is highlight the best match `FirstName` when user type a key. But having issue when `T` typed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default the ListView implements text searching ability. You can stop this behavious byusing the IsTextSearchEnabled property on the list box. Try

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
      IsTextSearchEnabled="False">
```

This should disable the text search when you do not want it.

Comment: Thanks. That's the solution I look for.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
After some investigation I found next solution:

```
<ListView 
    TextSearch.TextPath="FirstName"
    ...>
```

Hope this will help.

**Original answer:**

Just override `ToString()` on View Model and you will get proper behavior.

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But overriding the ToString() is not the best solution here.